# Implementing dynamic forms in ExtJS

Tags: json, extjs, dynamic

I am doing preliminary analysis for turning static forms in an ExtJS 5.x app into dynamic ones, since there is a lot of redundancy in several of the app's forms in terms of structure and this would allow for ease of creation in new forms with similar structure.

One issue I cannot wrap my head around is how to deal with event listeners in terms of JSONifying them. For example, I have the following listener attached to a button:

```
{
    "xtype": 'button',
    "text": 'Constrain search by date range',
    "itemId": 'showWhen',
    "hidden": false,
    listeners: {
        click: function (button) {
            button.up('grid').down('#whenId').show();
            button.up('grid').down('#whenValue').show();
            button.up('grid').down('#hideWhen').show();
            button.up('grid').down('#showWhen').hide();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass the `up`, `down`, etc., methods as JSON? Or, more generally, how do I deal with the entire listener object?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can relegate the listener to a ViewController with a defined scope attribute. See [ViewControllerArchitecture](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/view_controllers.html)... I should have figured this out, since I had been using the view's `controller` named scope to pass off handler logic via name reference to the view's ViewController. Pretty cool!